# Joomla menu styling first child

Tags: html, css, menu, joomla, styling

i have a menu:

```
<li id="current" class="selected parent item556">
<a href="#">Parent</a>
<ul>
    <li class="item557">
        <a href="#">Child</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item558">
        <a href="#">Child</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

And i want to style only the Parent "a" element, but it styles all the Child elements too, since their are under the parent "li".
I tried something like:

```
li#current a:first-child{
color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

Didn't work, how do i style only the Parent "a"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the immediate child operator `>` to target the link (i.e. only links directly in the `li` element):

```
li#current > a
```

Comment: Just keep in mind, this will target all `a` tags that in the first level of the `li`, not just the first `a`.  So it works 100% with your example now, but if you add more `a` tags later you will need to adjust the selector.

Comment: Alright, adjusted it a bit and your post was very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try: `li#current a:first-of-type` to get the first `a`

Or you can try: `li#current:nth-child(1)` to get the first child